# MsalAuthProvider in React error : 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IAzureADProps'

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am using : react-aad-msal for authentication to Azure from an react-app.

I have configured my authprovider as per documentation : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aad-msal#msal-configuration

All is ok and it seems to be working at least a little. But when I try and wrap it around over components like this :

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AzureAD provider={authProvider}>
      <App/>
    </AzureAD>
   </React.StrictMode>
```

I am getting the error of :

```
ype '{ children: Element; provider: MsalAuthProvider; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IAzureADProps'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IAzureADProps'
```

Has anyone come across this problem before ? This is driving me mad...

Comment: Are you using react 18.2.0 version, which is the latest version for now ? if yes there is a hack try to downgrade your react to 18.1.0 or 18.0.0

Comment: same here, any working solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-react instead? This is the official Authentication library supported by Microsoft for React.